# Entire function such that the order is an $\inf $ and not a $\min$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

An entire function is of finite order $\rho$ if $$\rho = \inf \{\lambda \geq 0  \ | \ \exists A, B > 0 \ s.t. \  |f(z)|\leq Ae^{B|z|^{\lambda}} \forall z \in \mathbb{C} \}$$  I need an example of an entire function of finite order such that this $\inf$ is not a $\min$.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many:
1. any non-constant polynomial $P_n(z)$;
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^{n^{1+\varepsilon}}}\,,\;\;\varepsilon>0$;
3.  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n}}{n^{n^{1+\varepsilon}}}\,,\;\;\varepsilon>0$;
4. *etc.*

Comment: @mkl314: I don't understand points $2.$ and $3.$, what's the order of those functions ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an hint: Try $f(z) = e^{2z}$

Comment: What am I missing? The infimum is attained, so it is a minimum for that function.